# How do you find a "."?

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit

I'm trying to create a regular expression to look for filenames from full file paths, but it should not return for just a directory. For example, `C:\Users\IgneusJotunn\Desktop\file.doc` should return `file.doc` while `C:\Users\IgneusJotunn\Desktop\folder` should find no matches. These are all Word or Excel files, but I prefer not to rely on that. This:

```
StringRegExp($string, "[^\\]*\z",1)
```

finds whatever is after the last slash, but can't differentiate files from folders. This:

```
StringRegExp($string, "[^\\]*[dx][ol][cs]\z",1)
```

almost works, but is an ugly hack and there may be docx or xlsx files. Plus, files could be named like `MyNamesDoc.doc`. Easily solved if I could search for a period, but `.` is a used character (it means any single character except a newline) which does not seem to work with escapes. This:

```
StringRegExp($ue_string, "[^\\]*\..*\z",1)
```

should work, finding anything after the last backslash, capturing only something with a period in it. How to incorporate a period? Or any way to just match files?

Edit: Answered my own question. I'm interested in why it wasn't working and if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Go ahead and make a folder right now and put a period in it. Totally valid syntax. `My.Folder.Of.Awesome` for example. `/ ? < > \ : * | ”` are some illegal characters, but periods are fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Local $string = StringRegExp($string, "[^\\]*\.doc\z|[^\\]*\.docx\z|[^\\]*\.xls\z|[^\\]*\.xlsx\z",1)
```

Periods do in fact work with the same escape slash most special characters use. As for the document type, an Or pipe and a different extension works great. If for some reason you need to add an extension, just add another Or.

Answer (score 1):

Meh, I'm bored.  You could do this:

```
$sFile = StringRegExp($sPath, "[^\\]+\.(?:doc|xls)x?$", 1)
```

There's no guarantees that a folder wouldn't be named that, so to be absolutely certain you'd have to check the file/folder attributes.  However it's doubtful anyone would name a folder with something like '.docx'

Answer (score -1):

- Reverse the string.
- Look for the "."
- Look for "\" with StringInStr (and/or "/")
- Trim the right side from the return of StringinStr
- Reverse it again.